# What is the most optimized method to select all HTML Elements existing in an specific area?

Tags: javascript, dom, custom-selectors

### Is there any optimized way to select all DOM elements inside a rectangle?

To make the situation more clear I've brought some illustrations. Imagine we have an HTML page like this:

[image: page]

Now we're gonna select elements based on a specific rectangle.

```
const ourBox = {
    offsetTop: 1100,
    offsetLeft: 600,
    width: 400,
    height: 400
}

const elements = getAllElementsInsideBox(ourBox)

console.log(elements)
// Logs array of elements which have collisions with imagined box
```

[image: page+rect]

For the above box, selected elements will be the elements which are specified with blue border as it can be seen in the picture:

[image: page+rect+selected]

### Bonus Challenge

If it's not that hard to find the optimized code for rectangle, let's make it more challenging by selecting elements inside a circle. The code will be like:

```
const ourCircle = {
    centerTop: 1200,
    centerLeft: 500,
    radius: 150
}

const elements = getAllElementsInsideCircle(ourCircle)

console.log(elements)
// Logs array of elements which have collisions with the imagined circle
```

[image: page+circle]

This is a challenge for me and I'm working on it. If I found the best solution I will share with you here, also I'll be appreciated if you share your solution with me.

> Note: Checking all elements offsets one by one is a way, but maybe not that optimized! let's try in different ways.

Comment: Using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: _This is a challenge for me and I'm working on it._ - So let us know when you run into a road block and we'll be ready to assist.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The `Intersection Observer API` you've mentioned is so cool and it's new to me.

In addition, there are no multiple questions, forget about the circle, **I want to find elements which have intersections with a specific rectangle**. Just this. If we can select them by circle it's way better but it's not necessary for now.

I'm looking at the link you've sent. Much appreciations